# d3.js: How to change a nodes' representation in a force-layout graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, force-layout

I am trying to expand [this force layout example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045) by changing a nodes' shape from circle to rectangle when it is clicked. So I don't want to change any data but just want to replace the corresponding SVG element.

One of my approaches looked like this:

```
     node.on("click", function() {
        this.remove();
        svg.selectAll(".node").data(graph.nodes).enter().append("rect")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .attr("width", 5).attr("height", 5)
                .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); });
    });
```

So I removed the SVG element from the DOM and rebound the data, adding a rectangle for the now missing node.

Unfortunately this does not work (the force layout does not set any properties on the new element) and I have no idea if this a reasonable approach at all.

Any ideas how to do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way.

```
node.on("click", function(d) {
  var size = d.weight * 2 + 12;
  d3.select(this).select("circle").remove();
  d3.select(this).append("rect")
    .attr("x", -(size / 2))
    .attr("y", -(size / 2))
    .attr("height", size)
    .attr("width", size)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return color(1 / d.rating);
    });
});
```

Working code snippet -

```js
var graph = {
  "nodes": [{
    "name": "1",
    "rating": 90,
    "id": 2951
  }, {
    "name": "2",
    "rating": 80,
    "id": 654654
  }, {
    "name": "3",
    "rating": 80,
    "id": 6546544
  }, {
    "name": "4",
    "rating": 1,
    "id": 68987978
  }, {
    "name": "5",
    "rating": 1,
    "id": 9878933
  }, {
    "name": "6",
    "rating": 1,
    "id": 6161
  }, {
    "name": "7",
    "rating": 1,
    "id": 64654
  }, {
    "name": "8",
    "rating": 20,
    "id": 354654
  }, {
    "name": "9",
    "rating": 50,
    "id": 8494
  }, {
    "name": "10",
    "rating": 1,
    "id": 6846874
  }, {
    "name": "11",
    "rating": 1,
    "id": 5487
  }, {
    "name": "12",
    "rating": 80,
    "id": "parfum_kenzo"
  }, {
    "name": "13",
    "rating": 1,
    "id": 65465465
  }, {
    "name": "14",
    "rating": 90,
    "id": "jungle_de_kenzo"
  }, {
    "name": "15",
    "rating": 20,
    "id": 313514
  }, {
    "name": "16",
    "rating": 40,
    "id": 36543614
  }, {
    "name": "17",
    "rating": 100,
    "id": "Yann_YA645"
  }, {
    "name": "18",
    "rating": 1,
    "id": 97413
  }, {
    "name": "19",
    "rating": 1,
    "id": 97414
  }, {
    "name": "20",
    "rating": 100,
    "id": 976431231
  }, {
    "name": "21",
    "rating": 1,
    "id": 9416
  }, {
    "name": "22",
    "rating": 1,
    "id": 998949
  }, {
    "name": "23",
    "rating": 100,
    "id": 984941
  }, {
    "name": "24",
    "rating": 100,
    "id": "99843"
  }, {
    "name": "25",
    "rating": 1,
    "id": 94915
  }, {
    "name": "26",
    "rating": 1,
    "id": 913134
  }, {
    "name": "27",
    "rating": 1,
    "id": 9134371
  }],
  "links": [{
    "source": 6,
    "target": 5,
    "value": 6,
    "label": "publishedOn"
  }, {
    "source": 8,
    "target": 5,
    "value": 6,
    "label": "publishedOn"
  }, {
    "source": 7,
    "target": 1,
    "value": 4,
    "label": "containsKeyword"
  }, {
    "source": 8,
    "target": 10,
    "value": 3,
    "label": "containsKeyword"
  }, {
    "source": 7,
    "target": 14,
    "value": 4,
    "label": "publishedBy"
  }, {
    "source": 8,
    "target": 15,
    "value": 6,
    "label": "publishedBy"
  }, {
    "source": 9,
    "target": 1,
    "value": 6,
    "label": "depicts"
  }, {
    "source": 10,
    "target": 1,
    "value": 6,
    "label": "depicts"
  }, {
    "source": 16,
    "target": 1,
    "value": 6,
    "label": "manageWebsite"
  }, {
    "source": 16,
    "target": 2,
    "value": 5,
    "label": "manageWebsite"
  }, {
    "source": 16,
    "target": 3,
    "value": 6,
    "label": "manageWebsite"
  }, {
    "source": 16,
    "target": 4,
    "value": 6,
    "label": "manageWebsite"
  }, {
    "source": 19,
    "target": 18,
    "value": 2,
    "label": "postedOn"
  }, {
    "source": 18,
    "target": 1,
    "value": 6,
    "label": "childOf"
  }, {
    "source": 17,
    "target": 19,
    "value": 8,
    "label": "describes"
  }, {
    "source": 18,
    "target": 11,
    "value": 6,
    "label": "containsKeyword"
  }, {
    "source": 17,
    "target": 13,
    "value": 3,
    "label": "containsKeyword"
  }, {
    "source": 20,
    "target": 13,
    "value": 3,
    "label": "containsKeyword"
  }, {
    "source": 20,
    "target": 21,
    "value": 3,
    "label": "postedOn"
  }, {
    "source": 22,
    "target": 20,
    "value": 3,
    "label": "postedOn"
  }, {
    "source": 23,
    "target": 21,
    "value": 3,
    "label": "manageWebsite"
  }, {
    "source": 23,
    "target": 24,
    "value": 3,
    "label": "manageWebsite"
  }, {
    "source": 23,
    "target": 25,
    "value": 3,
    "label": "manageWebsite"
  }, {
    "source": 23,
    "target": 26,
    "value": 3,
    "label": "manageWebsite"
  }]
}


var margin = {
  top: -5,
  right: -5,
  bottom: -5,
  left: -5
};
var width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
  .charge(-200)
  .linkDistance(50)
  .size([width + margin.left + margin.right, height + margin.top + margin.bottom]);

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1, 10])
  .on("zoom", zoomed);

var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
  .origin(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .on("dragstart", dragstarted)
  .on("drag", dragged)
  .on("dragend", dragended);


var svg = d3.select("#map").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.right + ")")
  .call(zoom);

var rect = svg.append("rect")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .style("fill", "none")
  .style("pointer-events", "all");

var container = svg.append("g");

//d3.json('http://blt909.free.fr/wd/map2.json', function(error, graph) {

force
  .nodes(graph.nodes)
  .links(graph.links)
  .start();



var link = container.append("g")
  .attr("class", "links")
  .selectAll(".link")
  .data(graph.links)
  .enter().append("line")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .style("stroke-width", function(d) {
    return Math.sqrt(d.value);
  });

var node = container.append("g")
  .attr("class", "nodes")
  .selectAll(".node")
  .data(graph.nodes)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })
  .call(drag);

node.append("circle")
  .attr("r", function(d) {
    return d.weight * 2 + 12;
  })
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return color(1 / d.rating);
  });


force.on("tick", function() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    });

  node.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
  });
});

var linkedByIndex = {};
graph.links.forEach(function(d) {
  linkedByIndex[d.source.index + "," + d.target.index] = 1;
});

function isConnected(a, b) {
  return linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index] || linkedByIndex[b.index + "," + a.index];
}

node.on("click", function(d) {
  var size = d.weight * 2 + 12;
  d3.select(this).select("circle").remove();
  d3.select(this).append("rect")
    .attr("x", -(size / 2))
    .attr("y", -(size / 2))
    .attr("height", size)
    .attr("width", size)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return color(1 / d.rating);
    });
});

function dottype(d) {
  d.x = +d.x;
  d.y = +d.y;
  return d;
}

function zoomed() {
  container.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}

function dragstarted(d) {
  d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();

  d3.select(this).classed("dragging", true);
  force.start();
}

function dragged(d) {

  d3.select(this).attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x).attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y);

}

function dragended(d) {

  d3.select(this).classed("dragging", false);
}
```

```css
.node {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.node-active {
  stroke: #555;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.link {
  stroke: #555;
  stroke-opacity: .3;
}
.link-active {
  stroke-opacity: 1;
}
.overlay {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}
#map {
  border: 2px #555 dashed;
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you. Using a SVG group-element as container for the shape did the trick. This way the data is bound to the container and I can change the contained shape easily.

Answer (score 0):

You've updated the dom elements, but not the array used by the force layout algorithm, so do this as the last line in the on click function:

```
graph.nodes = svg.selectAll(".node");
```

(You might also find without a data key function that random nodes get changed to rectangles rather than the one you clicked)

Comment: I don't think this is correct. `graph.nodes` is the actual data that is bound to the graph while `svg.selectAll(".node")` returns a selection of DOM nodes.

Comment: But you are right, that the nodes change randomly (although I don't really understand the problem). I don't experience this randomness in the solution of @Gilsha though. Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Comment: ah you right, I've got that wrong, I worked off an example that used the graph variable differently to your example. PS. The 'randomness' is tied in to the fact when you rebind the data you need a key function, otherwise it will just bind the data to selected elements in the order it finds them, so the last data item is bound to the new element, whether it was the last data item that needed that done or not.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for the clarification!