# In d3 force directed, how do I change a nodes shape by clicking on it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, svg, graph

I have a force directed graph in d3, and want to be able to click on the circular nodes and have them turn into rectangles. Then if I click on a rectangle, I'd like it to revert to a circle.

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35258484/d3-js-how-to-change-a-nodes-representation-in-a-force-layout-graph) and related questions on SO, but I think they are for earlier versions of D3, and do not work for me.

I can make it so the size and colour of my circles will change on click, and with the following code I can have the circle node replaced with a black rect, however it is not attached to the graph and is just a black square on the svg.

```
node.on("click", function(d,i) {

      var size = 20;
      d3.select(this).remove();

      svg.append("rect")
          .attr("x", d.x)
          .attr("y", d.y)
          .attr("height", size)
          .attr("width", size)
          .style("fill", function(d) {
            return color( d.group);
          });
})
```

Can anyone show me what I'm missing? I suspect `rect` is not being attached to the graph data but I am not familar enough with d3 to understand what I should change. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes little sense when you say:

> I have looked at this and related questions on SO, but I think they are for earlier versions of D3, and do not work for me.

It seems to me that nothing in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35262760/5768908) suggests that it won't work in D3 v4.x. It's worth mentioning that, in the answer (and the question) you linked, `node` is a group element, and therefore `this` refers to the group, not to the circle/rectangle.

Moving on, a possible solution (which doesn't involve removing and appending elements) is to simulate a circle with a rectangle:

```
node.append("rect")
    .attr("width", 16)
    .attr("height", 16)
    .attr("rx", 8)
    .attr("ry", 8)
```

And, inside the click function, changing `rx` and `ry`:

```
function click() {
    if(d3.select(this).attr("rx") == 8){
        d3.select(this).attr("rx", 0).attr("ry", 0);
    } else {
        d3.select(this).attr("rx", 8).attr("ry", 8);};
};
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var nodes = [
  {"id": 1},
  {"id": 2},
  {"id": 3},
  {"id": 4},
  {"id": 5},
  {"id": 6},
  {"id": 7},
  {"id": 8},
  {"id": 9},
  {"id": 10},
  {"id": 11},
  {"id": 12}
];

var links = [
  {source: 1, target: 8},
  {source: 1, target: 3},
  {source: 1, target: 4},
 {source: 1, target: 9},
 {source: 1, target: 10},
 {source: 1, target: 11},
  {source: 2, target: 5},
  {source: 2, target: 6},
 {source: 2, target: 7},
 {source: 2, target: 12},
  {source: 2, target: 4},
 {source: 2, target: 8},
  {source: 6, target: 7},
  {source: 6, target: 8},
  {source: 6, target: 9},
 {source: 6, target: 5},
  {source: 6, target: 3},
  {source: 6, target: 9},
]

var index = 10;
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    node,
    link;

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
  .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(30))
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

update();
function update() {
  link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; })

  link = link.enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("class", "link");

  node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id; })

  node = node.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node");

  node.append("rect")
  .attr("width", 16)
    .attr("height", 16)
  .attr("rx", 8)
  .attr("ry", 8)
  .attr("fill", "teal")
  .on("click", click);

  simulation
      .nodes(nodes)
      .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
      .links(links);
}


function click() {
  if(d3.select(this).attr("rx") == 8){d3.select(this).attr("rx", 0).attr("ry", 0);}
 else{d3.select(this).attr("rx", 8).attr("ry", 8);};
}

function ticked() {
  link
      .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x + 8; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y + 8; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x+ 8; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y+ 8; });

  node
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + ", " + d.y + ")"; });
}
```

```css
.link {
  stroke: #aaa;
}

.node {
  stroke: none;
  stroke-width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="400" height="300"></svg>
```

Comment: Thank you. Looking at your answer I see that I did not notice the changes to the ticked() code in the other SO answer I was talking about, which may be why it wasn't working for me.